# Orbeon JavaScript Embedding error: `ORBEON.xforms.server.AjaxServer.Event is not a constructor`

Tags: javascript, orbeon

I am trying to use the JavaScript Orbeon embedding API. After setting up the forwarding* (I hope correctly, I had 404 first, then CORS error) now the form is embedded into the page but the form does not work, clicking on any control/button leads to an error
`ORBEON.xforms.server.AjaxServer.Event is not a constructor`.

More specifically clicking the next page button yields in console:

```
xforms.js:2399
⌄ Uncaught TypeError: ORBEON.xforms.server.AjaxServer.Event is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.focus (xforms.js:2399)
focus @ xforms.js:2399
---
xforms.js:2722 
⌄ Uncaught TypeError: ORBEON.xforms.server.AjaxServer.Event is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.click (xforms.js:2722)
click @ xforms.js:2722
```

---

* The forwarding is set up like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ....
    SSLProxyEngine on
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule    "^/orbeon/(.+)"  "https://orbeon.server.ip/orbeon/$1"  [P,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JS Embedding API Limitations](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/javascript-api#limitations) state, that

> `oxf.xforms.combine-resources` must be set to `true`

(in `properties-local.xml`)